# Define PHP version for Ansible composer module

Tags: php, ansible, composer-php

I run the following task in some deploy script for a PHP application:

```
- name: Update composer dependencies
  composer:
    command: update
    working_dir: "{{ release_path }}/src"
    ignore_platform_reqs: true
```

On the target system the CLI PHP version is `7.3`, but there is also a `/usr/bin/php7.2` binary, that I want to use.

How can I use the composer module and run a specific PHP version with it... or do I need to run this via the shell module like this?

```
- name: Update composer dependencies
  shell: "/usr/bin/php7.2 composer update"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ release_path }}/src"
```

Comment: On my end `/usr/bin/composer` ist executable and has the she-bang `#!/usr/bin/php`. I would check if that symlink `/usr/bin/php` is pointing to the correct  php binary (`ls -l /usr/bin/php`). After that you can shell run `composer` directly from your ansible script, and all other tools calling php will use the correct version, too.

Comment: @MichaelD. Thanks for this but this is not an option. The default `php` should point to the current php 7.3 version. I just want to run this specific command with another php version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Ansible doc for [Composer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/composer_module.html) there is an option for specifying the php executable one wants to use.

So you can use something like below for your case

```
- name: Update composer dependencies
  composer:
    command: update
    working_dir: "{{ release_path }}/src"
    ignore_platform_reqs: true
    executable: /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Comment: I totally overlooked this option. Thanks, that is the solution.